# xcode check if JSON Array contains value

Tags: iphone, arrays, json

I am returning a JSON array:
Array 2: ( {"checkin_ID" = 123}, {"checkin_ID" = 121;}, {"checkin_ID" = 99;}, etc)

In my code each cell has it's own checkin_ID.  If the checkin_ID of the cell matches any number or string from my JSON array, I would like to show a button.

Any ideas?

Code:

ViewDidLoad:

```
NSError *error = nil; NSDictionary *dict2 = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData2 error&error2]; 

if (dict2) { 
    rows2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"likes"]; 
}
```

Cell Construction:

```
NSPredicate *checkinIDPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checkin_ID == %d", myInt]; 

NSArray *matchingCheckins = [rows2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:checkinIDPredicate];

if([matchingCheckins count] > 0) // Show the button, etc.
```

In my `NSLog` after adding your code... Predicate checkin_ID = 121 Matching Predicate ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, parse your data into an array of dictionaries, storing it in a property for later use.

```
NSError *error = nil;
self.checkins = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:checkinData options:0 error:&error];
```

`checkinData` is an `NSData` object, which can be created easily from your JSON string.

When the cell for the row is being constructed, filter the list of checkins by your target ID:

```
NSPredicate *checkinIDPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checkin_ID == %d", cellCheckinID];
NSArray *matchingCheckins = [self.checkins filteredArrayUsingPredicate:checkinIDPredicate];
if([matchingCheckins count] > 0)
    // Show the button, etc.
```

This code has not been tested, so it may contain compiler or logic errors, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I am using CJSONDeserializer code below: `NSError *error = nil; NSDictionary *dict2 = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData2 error&error2]; if (dict2) { rows2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"likes"]; }` ____________ `NSPredicate *checkinIDPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checkin_ID == %d", myInt]; NSArray *matchingCheckins = [rows2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:checkinIDPredicate]; if([matchingCheckins count] > 0) // Show the button, etc.` In my NSLog after adding your code... Predicate checkin_ID = 121 Matching Predicate ()

Comment: Don't use TouchJSON. It's basically the worst JSON library for iOS. Other than that, perhaps you can update your question with some of your code, since the code formatting in comments is very difficult to read.

Comment: updated question with code...my app is embedded with TouchJson...would be difficult to change at this point.  What issues are there?  Seems to work well for most things.  Anyways, your code works except for the Matching Predicate portion returns nothing.

Comment: TouchJSON is slower by an order of magnitude than more modern JSON libraries. I doubt it would be that hard to find-and-replace all instances of serialization and deserialization with calls to `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: As for the issue at hand, the reason the results array is empty is because the predicate is failing to match any of the objects. Have you tried NSLog'ing the "likes" array once you deserialize it to see what it actually contains?

Comment: Hmmm...my queries do seem slow.  I will look into switching. Any reason I couldn't switch some JSONTouch to NSJSON to benchmark?

My likes contains only the checkin_ID's:  Array2: ({"checkin_ID" = 123;}, etc...

Comment: Yes, you can and should do performance testing. I'm not interested in what the serialized data contains; I'm interested in whether or not it actually makes it into the dictionary at runtime.